# Setting Up Win2008 R2 Server - IIS_IUSRS Permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, iis-7.5

I am setting up a web server and notice out the box it gives **IIS_IUSRS** read & execute (and as a result list folder contents) permissions on the wwwroot. I'm trying to make sure its secure as possible, and just wondering if its ok to leave that?

On my last server (Win2003) I only gave 'read' permissions to users on the wwwroot and then manually added the write / execute permissions on folders as needed.

Just wondering if everyone else leaves the permissions as they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go through the article http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/140/understanding-the-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis-70/. As TomTom said, yes security has changed a lot from what it was in IIS 6.0. The article gives good in-depth on the User and Group level changes that has happened in IIS 7.0.

Below is part from the Web site link and from the help available in IIS 7.

> IIS_IUSRS group has been granted
>   access on all the necessary file and
>   system resources so that an account,
>   when added to this group, can act as
>   an application pool identity
>   seamlessly. By default, the
>   ApplicationPoolIdentity account is
>   selected. The ApplicationPoolIdentity
>   account is dynamically created when an
>   application pool is started, and
>   therefore this account provides the
>   most security for your applications.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my understanding:

According to [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/140/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis-7/):

> IIS 7 also makes the process of
> configuring an application pool
> identity and making all necessary
> changes easier. When IIS starts a
> worker process, it needs to create a
> token that the process will use. When
> this token is created, IIS 7
> automatically adds the IIS_IUSRS
> membership to the worker processes
> token at runtime. The accounts that
> run as 'application pool identities'
> no longer need to be an explicit part
> of the IIS_IUSRS group. This change
> helps you to set up your systems with
> fewer obstacles and makes your overall
> experience more favorable.

So, it could be said no matter which account we use as a Application Pool Identity, this account will be given the IIS_IUSRS group permission at runtime ***dynamically and implicitly***. This ***so-called*** convenience is claimed to provide the ***most*** security. Anyway, who doesn't want IIS_IUSRS permissions if the account is running as an Application Pool Identity. But I just like everything to be in the sun.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't like it: turn on manualGroupMembership :)

Comment: Thanks for reminding~ now I have one more thing to take care of... >_<

Answer (score 0):

I suggest y oureally read up on the permission handling in IIS 7 - it is TOTALLY different from the one you know. Totally ;)

I normally set up:
* One user for every website
* One application pool fo revery website, runing under the user identity
* That is it - rights go to the application user.